# Dummy monitor in 21.10

Tags: xorg, monitor, gdm, 21.10

Until 20.04 I was able to create a fake monitor for remote access of an headless machine in this way:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-session gdm3
$ sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target

$ sudo apt install  xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04
$ sudo apt install  xserver-xorg-video-dummy

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "dummy"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 31.5-48.5
    VertRefresh 50-70
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

It worked like a charm, allowing me to connect using a remote desktop application.
Instead, for 21.10 this procedure leads to a "Oh no, something has gone wrong" death page.

**How should I change this in order to get the dummy monitor functionality working again?**

I'm aware I can use an hardware plug, but this is not the question.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on 22.04:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "dummy"
    VideoRam 256000
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 5.0 - 1000.0
    VertRefresh 5.0 - 200.0
    ModeLine "1920x1080" 148.50 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +Hsync +Vsync
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080" "1280x800" "1024x768" "1920x1080" "1440x900"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I pulled different Modelines from https://gist.github.com/divinity76/ce210b5dbcd9ea7d0585ac403caef577